# Java Camel FTP Upload

Tags: java, ftp, apache-camel, esb

First, sorry for my bad english.

The problem is I can not upload a file (.xls) file on a local FTP server.

This is the Exception :

```
[org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - Error writing file GAS_EAV_EMV.xls]
```

This is my route :

```
<route id="sendFtp">
    <from uri="direct:sendFtp"/>
    <setHeader headerName="CamelFileName">
        <simple>GAS_EAV_EMV.xls</simple>
    </setHeader>
    <process ref="egssisFtpProcessor"/>
    <to uri="ftp://foo@127.0.0.1:21/?password=pwd"/>
</route>
```

Here my Processor to attach the file :

```
public class EgssisFtpProcessor implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String filename = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, String.class);
        exchange.getIn().addAttachment(filename, new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(filename)));
    }
}
```

The exchange object has the attachment at the end of the processor.

It works with the SMTP protocol but not with FTP.

Any idea ?

Server log :

```
[14:29:29] - [78] Connecté à 127.0.0.1. Collecte du Nom d'utilisateur.
[14:29:29] - [78] Usager FOO Connecté IP: 127.0.0.1
[14:29:29] - [78] FOO : Répertoire en Cours: C:\tmp\
[14:29:29] - [78] Client 127.0.0.1 Déconnecté (00:00:00 Min)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attachements is not used. Instead just set the message body to a java.io.File for the file you want to upload.

```
exchange.getIn().setBody(new File(filename));
```

And since you use XML you may want to do this without any java code. You can use the message translator EIP to convert the message body to a java.io.File with the header as the file name.

```
<transform>
    <simple resultType="java.io.File">${header.CamelFileName}</simple>
</transform>
```